# how to use substring-after() and substring-before() with 'and' and 'or' operators in multiple strings

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

im trying to take substring of a element with xpath,

```
<table>
  <tr><td>color : blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td>color - green</td></tr>
  <tr><td>jasmine flower</td></tr>
</table>
```

**td** tag contains the color values *blue* and *green* seperated by a hyphen or a colon

i have xpath for substring-after colon `//tr/td/substring-after(text(),':')` which gives me output **blue** and for substring-after hypen `//tr/td/substring-after(text(),'-')` which gives me output **green**

but i want to merge both xpath codes into one single code

i tried the following code
`//tr/td/[substring-after(text(),':') or substring-after(text(),'-')]`
which gives me output like this

```
[true]
[true]
[false]
```

and   `//tr/td/text()[substring-after(.,':') or substring-after(.,'-')]`
which gives output like

```
color : blue
color - green
```

what I need is

```
blue
green
```

need a single line code

> note : im testing my code in http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Comment: try `//tr/td/substring-after(text(),':'), //tr/td/substring-after(text(),'-')`

Comment: This can be done with quite a simple XPath 2.0 expression -- see below.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `string-join(//td[matches(., '[:\-]')]/tokenize(., '[:\-]')[2], ' ')` or perhaps `string-join(//td[matches(., '[:\-]')]/tokenize(., '\s*[:\-]\s*')[2], ' ')`.

Comment: Another option would be to use the `replace` function: `//tr/td[matches(., '[:\-]')]/replace(., '^.*[:\-]\s*(.*)$', '$1')`

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as**:

```
for $t in /*/tr/td/text()[1]/translate(., '-',':')
  return substring-after($t, ':')
```

**XSLT- based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "for $t in /*/tr/td/text()[1]/translate(., '-',':')
      return substring-after($t, ':')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>color : blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td>color - green</td></tr>
  <tr><td>jasmine flower</td></tr>
</table>
```

**The XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
 blue  green
```